# Android Songs lyrics app with XML db

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-intent

Let me first describe my intention. I have a XML DB with some folklore songs and lyrics. For my family and friends I want to develop an android app that will list the songs in *A-Z* order and after clicking/touching the song title a text/lyrics will appear (so that we can all sing the same words).

I am not very familiar with Java and Android development, nevertheless I managed to create an App where in the first `Activity` there is a button "Show all songs" and after pressing it another `Activity` with `ListView` lists the songs (using `XMLPullHandler` parser). `Collections.sort()` takes care for ordering (although not 100%, because items which start with national characters are pushed to the end). See the screenshot please:

[image: Screenshot of current functionality]

But now I am uncertain how to proceed with the display of the song-text. My ideas:

1. To achieve, that after clicking an item a new `SongActivity` will appear and will show the lyrics. But then I should create e.g. 100 intents and activities or can I do it with just one? In the later case - how will the app know which text belongs to the clicked song?
2. To load the song lyrics text together with the song title and show it in the `ListView`, but with an attribute `invisible` (in html it is clear, but in java - I am not sure...)

Example of the song in the xml file:

```
<songs>
    <song>
        <id>1</id>
        <title>Zvalila sa skala</title>
        <lyrics>1.  [:Zvalila sa skala z vŕšku do Dunaja,:]
            [:prenes ma, má milá, prenes ma, má milá, veď je voda malá.:]

            2.  [:Ja bych ťa preniesla, hoc by bola väčšia,:]
            [:ale že som ti nie, ale že som ti nie, tvoja najmilejšia.:]

            3.  [:Keby ja vedela, kde môj milý býva,:]
            [:zaletela by som, zaletela by som, na jeho biely dom.:]
        </lyrics>
        <type>Valčík</type>
    </song> ...
```

Could someone please give me a hand and guidance in this? I would be most grateful.

[On the picture is the actual status with visible values of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEaWJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To achieve, that after clicking an item a new Song Activity will
>   appear and will show the lyrics. But then I should create e.g. 100
>   intents and activities, or can I do it with just one? In the later
>   case - how will the app know which text belongs to the clicked song?

No you don't have to write 100 intents or activities. You can use just one which is more generalized and convenient.

> To load the song lyrics text together with the song title and show it
>   in the listview, but with an attribute "invisible" (in html it is
>   clear, but in java - I am not sure...)

Though your question is not very clear, I guess you need to show the title of the song along with some text as a secondary text. You're trying to use `invisible` attribute gives me sense of hiding the secondary text and once the list item is clicked make the secondary text visible - is that it??

If I got you correctly, then you need to modify the adapter you're using for your `RecyclerView`. You need to customize your adapter and while binding each element of your list, you need to show/hide the secondary text by yourself by tracking which item is selected.

I would suggest you to use `RecyclerView` to show the list of songs in a list. To implement a `RecyclerView` with a custom adapter you'll find plenty of documentation over the internet. Here I'm attaching one example.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    // Define the ViewHolder for list item
    public class NormalViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public NormalViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Do whatever you want on clicking the list items 
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // And now in onCreateViewHolder you have to pass the correct view
    // while populating the list item.

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;

        v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_normal, parent, false);

        NormalViewHolder vh = new NormalViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    // Now bind the viewholders in onBindViewHolder
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {
            if (holder instanceof NormalViewHolder) {
                NormalViewHolder vh = (NormalViewHolder) holder;

                vh.bindView(position);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (data == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        // data is the ArrayList of items you want to show in your list
        return data.size();
    }

    // Now define getItemViewType of your own. 

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    // Now set the default ViewHolder for NormalViewHolder
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // Define elements of a row here
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // Find view by ID and initialize here
        }

        public void bindView(int position) {
            // bindView() method to implement actions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment Reaz, I will try it and will see if I can make it work.

Comment: Hi Reaz, so I decided for the first option. Anyway, added an OnItemClickListener to my class, so I knew which item was clicked on. This works fine. So, from my rookie's POV it seems like this: I have a listview with the data (song names) and an array, named piesne, which contains all of the information (also text_piesne particularly). On top of that I know which row (song title) was clicked on. Is it be possible, when the row is clicked, to open the new view and to pass to the new activity the text from the variable text_piesne? If so, how can I access e.g. the piesne[5].text_piesne? Thanks

Comment: I didn't understand your requirement fully as I already have mentioned how you can pass data between `Activity`. Anyway, if you need to explain the problem more, please write a different question in StackOverflow and give the link to the question here, so that I can get notified about it. I'll take a look at that question too then. Thanks.